# htaccess redirect rules conflict with eachother

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need to write my htaccess to do the following.

1) I want to redirect example.com/blog/whatever into blog.example.com/whatever (NO HTTPS)

2) example.com --> https://www.example.com (HTTPS and add WWW)

The following is my htaccess. The blog part works fine when it is uncommented,  but when I uncomment those two lines related to blog, the www.mydomain.com does not work anymore and I get nothing in the browser, not even 404. If I comment those two line (like it is now) then everything works fine but not the blog part.

Can someone please help me to figure this out so I can have both rules work at the same time.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80

#blog config 

#RewriteRule ^blog$ http://blog.example.com/ [P,L,R=301]

#RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ http://blog.example.com/$1 [P,L,R=301]


# forward all the request to https and www

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]


# Framework purposes

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

So basically the problem is when I have these two rules together (blog part and force https) they don't work together, however each individually work if I uncomment the other one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it for you.

```
RewriteEngine on

# Redirect blog
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ http://blog.example.com/$1 [NE,R=301,L]

# Redirect all HTTPS or non-www requests to HTTPS and www
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [NE,R=301,L]

# Framework purposes
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, SuperDuperApps. Would you please explain the difference to me. I really want to understand the problem.

Comment: And one more little problem which you may be able to help me is when the protocol is already https then this code does not add www to it. How can I force www for the https?

Comment: Yes I noticed the non-www HTTPS issue, I'll add a fix for that and get back to you about understanding it better.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: ok I added a fix for that. I think you already understand it quite well, so perhaps you could ask what you don't understand? I think the main thing you were missing was that the `RewriteCond` checking port 80 has to be paired with the HTTPS redirect. You had it at the top.

Comment: If you want to understand in detail, the documentation is very good at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/

Comment: Yes, I get it now, once again thanks for your help and thanks for the useful link you share.

Comment: Great, you were also using the `P` flag which is for proxying and not what you wanted.

Comment: Actually I wanted the proxy, because I dont want the URL change in the address bar. So now I just add SSL to blog.example.com and I want the blog to be also https and once I changed the http to https now there is a problem again and the blog part does not work. Would you please help me one more time. I am sorry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147306/discussion-between-amirali-shahinpour-and-superduperapps).

Comment: Can I ask you to post another question for this? Post your current `.htaccess` and the problem you are having getting it to work. Let me know when you post it and I'll be happy to take a look.

Comment: Unfortunately they dont allow me to post another question. I will get Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.

Comment: All I want is to redirect blog to https as well